# How to integral normal distribution with some variation in python quickly?

Tags: python, scipy

I am using the scipy to create a normal distribution pdf and want to integrate it

```
def normal_distribution_function(x):
    value = scipy.stats.norm.pdf(x,mean,std)
    value=value*x
    return value
inte1, err = quad(normal_distribution_function, 0, 1)
def normal_distribution2(x):
    value=scipy.stats.norm.pdf(x,mean,std)
    return value
inte2,err = quad(normal_distribution2,1,np.inf)
```

here is the example to integrate the normal distribution and the first function is to integrate with multiply with input x.

and i want to make a quick integrate which i write this way

```
def normal_distribution_function1(x,case):
    value = scipy.stats.norm.pdf(x,expect_reward,std1)
    if case==1:
        value=0
    elif case==2:
        value=value*(1-x)
    elif case==3:
        value=value*(1+x)-x
    elif case==4:
        value=value
    return value
case1=quad(normal_distribution_function1(case=1),1,np.inf)
case2=quad(normal_distribution_function1(case=2),0,1)
case3=quad(normal_distribution_function1(case=3),-1,0)
case4=quad(normal_distribution_function1(case=4),-np.inf,-1)
```

however , i got the error

```
TypeError: normal_distribution_function1() missing 1 required positional argument: 'x'
```

I can't find a way to solve it , can anyone help? thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your function `normal_distribution_function1(x,case)` takes two arguments but you only specified the second one: `case`.

In the following lines you need to also specify the first argument `x` :

```
case1=quad(normal_distribution_function1(case=1),1,np.inf)
case2=quad(normal_distribution_function1(case=2),0,1)
case3=quad(normal_distribution_function1(case=3),-1,0)
case4=quad(normal_distribution_function1(case=4),-np.inf,-1)
```

**Explanation:**

When you call `normal_distribution_function` python does not execute the function and this is why you are not getting any errors and therefore quad() method works. If you try to pass only one argument: `normal_distribution_function1(case=1)`, the compiler will complain because you can't execute this function without providing both arguments.

[image: explanation]

Comment: but in the first two example i don't need to input the x and can run it successfully, why the first two can run ?

Comment: First of all that is a different question. Secondly, you haven't shared the function quad in your code. So I can't answer it anyways.

Comment: sorry, quad is the function in scipy (from scipy.integrate import quad)

Comment: I see, thanks for help, and i post a fast way here.

Answer (score 1):

I find a much fast way to integrate , using the lambda

```
case2_function= lambda x : scipy.stats.norm.pdf(x,expect_reward,std1) *(1-x)
case3_function = lambda x: scipy.stats.norm.pdf(x,expect_reward,std1) *(1+x)-x
case2,err2=quad(case2_function,0,1)
case3.err3=quad(case3_function,-1,0)
```

Thanks Marios Karamanis help!